# Android - Button height not decreasing to wrap text

Tags: android, button, layout

I set the button's height via XML. Suppose it to be X

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_contnet"
    android:textSize = " <X> dp"
    ....
    ....
/>
```

If I set X to greater than 15 dp, the button's height grows to fit the text. But when I set it to something lower like 2dp, the button's height doesn't change and I can see a thick border around it as shown below:-

[image: shown here]

As shown above, text size is so small but still height doesn't decrease!
How can I force it to be of appropriate height?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Font size does not depend on button height. If you set it too small to fit the text, you will get the result you observe

**EDIT**

`wrap_content` would usually do the trick, however Button class sets some layout parameters like margin, background so it takes more space. You may get rid of Button and use i.e. `TextView` class, styled by hand to match your design. `onClickListener` will work perfectly fine with it and you will get result you want and full control over your button

**EDIT 2**

As this is bit related - there's AutoFitTextView widget on Github that deals with automatic text size scalling: https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Comment: I want button height to depend on text! not vice-versa

Comment: `wrap_content` would usually do the trick, however `Button` class sets some layout params like margin, background so it takes more space. You may get rid of Button and use i.e. `TextView` class, styled by hand to match your design. onClickListener will work perfectly fine with it and you will get result you want and full control over your button

Answer (score 1):

Just Set android:minHeight="xxdp"